Filter Pandas Dataframe to rows containing a string OR variable using .str.contains()
I've read several other answers on this topic, but none seem to address my usage case: how can I specify a variable inside of .str.contains()?
I want to filter for rows that have a specific known (and fixed) string in a certain column OR that have a pre-determined variable somewhere in that column (substring). I want to use the variable to make the code flexible enough to return different summaries.
df.loc[ df['Column'].str.contains(variable|'test_string')
MWE:
d = {'Column': ['test_string', 'variable_string', 'Letter to the Editor', 'Letter variable_string to the Editor', 'Letter to the Editor']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

variable = 'variable_string'

# this works, but I don't want to hardcode the value of 'variable_string', I want that to be able to easily change run to run
df.loc[ df['Column'].str.contains('test_string|variable_string')]

# these don't
df.loc[ df['Column'].str.contains('test_string|'variable)]
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

df.loc[ df['Column'].str.contains('test_string'|variable)]
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Is this possible?

use an f-string: f'test_string|{variable}'. Why do you think this is any different from any other time when you want to get a variable into a string?

Amazing, thank you! I didn't think of that.
